# Apply global scope based on user role in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, eloquent, user-roles, laravel-query-builder, global-scope

For some model, I need to apply a global scope if the logged in user is not super admin. In model's `boot()` method I tried something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Auth;
use App\Scopes\RoleScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        if( Auth::check() && ! Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin() ){
            static::addGlobalScope(new RoleScope);
        }
    }
}
```

The scop never applied! What did I do wrong here? How can I achieve the goal to apply the scope based on the user role? thanks

Comment: Thie above code applies the scope is user IS NOT a superadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the currently authenticated user in the `boot` method of the Eloquent model - the Auth middleware hasn't run yet at this point.

What you should do is to perform the super admin check within the `apply` method of your `RoleScope`.